# What's the different between HttpClient.post() and new HttpRequest('POST') in angular?

Tags: angular, httprequest, httpclient

I am learning angular recently, and I find there are two way to make a POST request:

```js
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  httpClient.post(url, data, options);
}

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  const req = new HttpRequest('POST', url, init);
  httpClient.request(req);
}
```

So I want to know what is the different between them. Or they just two way to perform HTTP requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `post()` function is really just a helper function, and is equivalent to `request('POST', ...)`.

Checking the source at https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/client.ts, `post()` calls `request('POST')`, which creates a `HttpRequest` object when the string `'POST'` is passed in.  It isn't just as simple as that, as it wires up observables depending on options, etc, but that's what it is in essence.

Comment: Thank you very much!  It really solves my confusion.